# Generate KeyEvent from QML

Tags: qt, qml, keyevent

How can I generate a KeyEvent?

I have to show functionality on Keys.onPressed & events generated from my virtual keyboard.

So can I fake generate key Events when my Virtual Keyboard events are generated?

I could only find how to sendKeyEvents to QML from Qt, but I want to signal it from QML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly in QML.

What you can do is expose to your QML Virtual keyboard a custom Qt object that emits key signals when you want (e.g. by calling a method `YourCustomKeySignalGenerator::pressKey(YourKeyEnum pressedKey)` )

Comment: is there no way to emit signal from qml?

Comment: The tutorial mentioned above can now be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html).