# How to simulate button presses in pyside?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a Python(PySide) and Qt/QML UI that today responds to keyboard input (actually it's an IR remote control, but the input events are received as though they were coming from a keyboard).

I want to be able to also respond to mouse events.  So where today the user uses arrow keys to navigate to a particular button and presses OK (i.e., Return) to activate the handling for that button, I would like them to just be able to click the mouse on that button and get the same handling behavior.

**What I have so far:**

I've already got `Keys.onReturnPressed:` handling in my QML code that does what I need to do when the user presses OK/Return.  And I've added `MouseArea { ... onClicked: {...} ... }` QML code that recognizes when I click on a given control.  So I already see in my log when the mouse click events occur.

**My question:**

How do I tie them together?  **I want to make the `onClicked:` behavior just generate some kind of event (a signal, maybe?) that causes the `onReturnPressed:` handling to be invoked.**  (I'm not at all averse to passing events through the Python side of things if that's what it takes to make this work.)

(I guess I should mention here that the existing code includes some base classes (is that the right terminology here?) that can define behavior across ALL controls of a certain type (e.g., Buttons) in the system.  So while each of the many, many Buttons has its own `onReturnPressed:` code providing its unique handling, **my objective is to have a single `onClicked:` handler in the base class that makes all Buttons respond to clicks as they do to Return presses today**.)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

> BTW: Yes, I'm aware that there's a second problem here, too, of navigation.  That is, even once I've turned the mouse click into a press
>   of the Return key, I still have to solve the problem of associating it
>   with the right control on the screen.
>
> I sort of didn't want to muddy the waters by asking too many things at once. 
>   I'll get to that one
>   when I've got this one in hand.  (...unless you've got a simple solution already up your sleeve...  In that case I'm all ears.)

Comment: Why don't you create a function and call it both in the onClicked and in the onReturnPressed?

Comment: Thanks, Fabio.  I could do that. But if I use that approach I'll have to edit every one of the (hundreds of) existing controls.  I'm looking for a more universal solution that will leverage the handling of Return key events that's already built in to all of those controls.  I appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: (I've edited the question to hopefully clarify the issue that Fabio's suggestion exposed.)

Comment: I think you can generate a KeyEvent, but you can't do it in QML, you must use C++. Here two useful links: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530784/generate-keyevent-from-qml) - [2 (see the last comment)](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15496)